# Matching two data tables (Vlookup, dplyr, match(), left_join) keeping number of rows

Tags: r, merge, dplyr, left-join

I want to include the table "tech_distance" into my "first occurrences" table.
The two data tables:

```
head(first_occurrences)
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   Main, Second [6]
   year  Main Second  occurrence
   <int> <chr>  <chr>      <int>
1  1991  C09D   C08F          1
2  2002  A47C   A47D          1
3  2002  G10K   H05K          1
4  2004  G06G   C07K          1
5  2015  B64F   B64D          1
6  2015  H02G   B29C          1


head(tech_distance)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
    Main  tech_distance
   <fctr>         <dbl>
1   C09D           0.3
2   A47C           0.0
3   G10K           0.5
4   G06G           0.5
5   B64F           0.0
6   H02G           0.5
```

This is the result I want to get:

```
head(first_occurrences)
   Main year Second occurrence tech_distance
 1 A01B 2004   E21B          1           0.7
 2 A01B 2004   E21B          1           0.5
 3 A01B 2004   E21B          1           0.7
 4 A01B 2004   E21B          1           0.5
 5 A01B 2004   E21B          1           0.5
 6 A01B 2004   E21B          1           1.0
```

I have used mutate in dplyr:

```
first_occurrences <- data %>% 
 select(year = X3,Main = X7,Second = X8) %>% 
 group_by(Main,Second) %>% 
 mutate(occurrence = n(), tech_distance) %>% 
 filter(occurrence >= 0, occurrence <= 1, !(Main == Second))
```

But I get this error:

```
 Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
 Column `tech_distance` must be length 24 (the group size) or one, not 2
```

So I tried using merge():

```
first_occurrences <- merge(first_occurrences, tech_distance, by.x = "Main", by.y = "Main", all.x=T)
```

This seems to work but I get an enormous number of rows (240,217 entries)

```
 str(first_occurrences)
 'data.frame':  240217 obs. of  5 variables:
  $ Main         : chr  "A01B" "A01B" "A01B" "A01B" ...
  $ year         : int  2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 2004 ...
  $ Second       : chr  "E21B" "E21B" "E21B" "E21B" ...
  $ occurrence   : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  $ tech_distance: num  0.7 0.5 0.7 0.5 0.5 1 0.5 0.7 0.3 0 ...
```

while the datasets before were:

```
str(first_occurrences)
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 8015 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ year      : int  1991 2002 2002 2004 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 ...
 $ Main      : chr  "C09D" "A47C" "G10K" "G06G" ...
 $ Second    : chr  "C08F" "A47D" "H05K" "C07K" ...
 $ occurrence: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

str(tech_distance)
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   8015 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Main         : Factor w/ 815 levels "A01B","A01C",..: 345 62 684 651 265 749 328 735 173 788 ...
 $ tech_distance: num  0.3 0 0.5 0.5 0 0.5 0.5 0 0.5 0.5 ...
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to merge two dataframes keeping the same number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the above comment;

If tech_distance varies by multiple things, such as main and second, I would actually create a new column then use that to do the `left_join`.

```
    first_occurrences <- mutate(first_occurrences, ID = paste0(main, "_", second, "_", year)
    tech_distance <- mutate(tech_distance, ID = paste0(main, "_", second, "_", year)  
    combined_data <- dplyr::left_join(first_occurrences, tech_distance, by = "ID")
```

As for reordering columns, you can simply use `select(#order of columns separated by names, -ID)`

For others who may be reading this:

Assuming the tech_distance is specific per main, and not anything else, I would use:

```
combined_data <- dplyr::left_join(first_occurrences, tech_distance, by = "main")
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the `Main` columns all unique? If they are, then you can get a one-to-one match and your result will have 8015 rows. If there are duplicates, then you get a one-to-many match and get more rows.

Comment: well spotted :) they are not unique, what should I do in that case?

Comment: @Amleto You can try to make them unique with the `unique` function. Then either change the data or you may just have to do a one-to-many join.